# Как залить fullstack проект в один репозиторий гитхаб?

Tags: git, github

У меня есть папка **project** и там находятся папка **client** и папка **server**. Как их выложить в один репозиторий? Можете подробно объяснить, все откопала, до сих пор не получается. Говорят, что надо удалить .git, но у меня его нет.

Comment: `$ cd project && git init && git add client server && git commit -m poehali`

Comment: спасибо! получилось)